# TextView line break strategy for Korean/Hangul

Tags: java, android, textview, line-breaks

I am using Spannable text in a TextView with mixed English and Korean. This is giving me line breaks in weird places. See image below.

In iOS there is the NSMutableParagraphStyle option `setLineBreakStrategy:NSLineBreakStrategyHangulWordPriority` which works well.

I have searched near and far and found nothing for Android/Java. Is there an equivalent Korean/Hangul line break strategy in Android/Java?

[image: Bootstrap Korean Grammar]

Comment: Found these for Flutter https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59284#issuecomment-1781284351 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19584#issuecomment-1235005686 which may provide direction